$a^3 - a^2 - b^2$ is a perfect square
I'm trying to prove the following problem:

The prime numbers $a,b$ satisfying $a^3 - a^2 - b^2$ is a perfect
square, prove that $a=b$.

What I've tried so far is: let $$a^3 - a^2 - b^2 = c^2$$then$$a^2(a-1) = b^2 + c^2$$Skip special cases by supposing that $a,b > 3$, so $$a^2(a-1) \equiv a-1 \pmod 3$$and$$b^2 + c^2 \equiv 1 + c^2 \pmod 3$$Consequently$$a \equiv 2 + c^2 \pmod 3$$Since either $c^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, but $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, so $c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.
But I still cannot go far from this.

Source of the problem, please?

I can't handle the special case, $a\equiv1\bmod4$, $b=2$.

@JohnO, got it!

@GerryMyerson: the problem is from https://diendantoanhoc.org/topic/195161-ch%E1%BB%A9ng-minh-r%E1%BA%B1ng-a3-a2-b2-l%C3%A0-s%E1%BB%91-ch%C3%ADnh-ph%C6%B0%C6%A1ng-th%C3%AC-ab/
I thought about it for hours but could not go any far.

@GerryMyerson Thanks for letting me know. It's an excellent solution.

We have $a^2(a-1)=b^2+c^2$, $a$ and $b$ prime.
Case 1: $a=2$. Then $4=b^2+c^2$, so $b=2=a$.
Case 2: $a\equiv3\bmod4$. Then $a-1$ must be a sum of two squares, $a-1=r^2+s^2$, and $a^2(a-1)=(ar)^2+(as)^2$. For $ar$ to be prime, we need $r=1$, so $b^2+c^2=a^2+(as)^2$, so $a=b$.
Case 3: $a\equiv1\bmod4$. Then $b^2+c^2\equiv0\bmod4$, so $b$ and $c$ are even, so $b=2$, and we have $a^3-a^2-4=c^2$. The left side factors: $(a-2)(a^2+a+2)=c^2$. Now, $a^2+a+2=(a-2)(a+3)+8$, so if $a^2+a+2$ and $a-2$ have any common divisor $d>1$ then $d$ must be even, but that's impossible, since $d$ divides the odd number $a-2$. So $a-2$ and $a^2+a+2$ must both be perfect squares. But $a^2+a+2=m^2$ implies $(2a+1)^2+7=n^2$, where $n=2m$. The only way to write $7$ as a difference of two squares is $4^2-3^2$, so $2a+1=3$, $a=1$, contradiction.
Done.
(I have used many standard facts about sums of two squares, covered in every intro Number Theory text.)

Thank you. In the case 2, how can you derive that $a-1$ must be sum of two squares?

That's one of those "standard facts about sums of two squares, covered in every intro Number Theory text". If $xy^2$ is a sum of two squares, then $x$ must be a sum of two squares. It follows from knowing that a positive integer is a sum of two squares if and only if it can be written as $rs^2$ where no prime $p\equiv3\bmod4$ divides $r$.

@TaThanhDinh FYI, a somewhat alternative way to handle case $2$ is that, if $a\neq b$, then $a\nmid b$ and $a\nmid c$. Then $c$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $a$, so $b^2+c^2\equiv 0\pmod{a};\to;(bc^{-1})^2\equiv -1\pmod{a}$. However, $-1$ is a quadratic residue for odd primes $a$ only where $a\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. This is shown, for example, in the first supplement of the Supplements to Quadratic Reciprocity. ...

@TaThanhDinh (cont.) Also, note that since $a\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ means there's an integer $j$ where $a=4j+3;\to;a-1=2(2j+1)$. If we have $d$ being a value where $d^2\equiv 1\pmod{a}$, then $d^{a-1}\equiv (d^{2})^{2j+1}\equiv (-1)^{2j+1}\equiv -1\pmod{a}$. However, by Fermat's little theorem, we have $d^{a-1}\equiv 1\pmod{a}$ instead.
